# How do I make this ruby code into an argument?

Tags: ruby

Currently it outputs the reverse string using this code:

```
string = 'Hello World!'
my_reverse = String.new
i = 1; while i <= string.length
  my_reverse << string[-i]
  i+=1
end

puts my_reverse
```

But I want to write a method, `my_reverse`, which takes a string as an argument and returns the reversed string. Like so:

```
my_reverse("hello")
#=> "olleh"
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You already have all of the code

Comment: For one, you could just do [`string.reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-reverse) instead of having this method at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the code you already have in a method:

```
def my_reverse(string_to_reverse)

   reverse_string = String.new
   i = 1; while i <= string_to_reverse.length
     reverse_string << string_to_reverse[-i]
     i+=1
   end

   return reverse_string 

end
```

and then call it like so:

```
>> my_reverse("Hello World")
```

You should note that a method already exists to do this: [string.reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-reverse). Even then, this particular implementation of reverse isn't the best.